# Python datetime isoformat - count days until bithday from string - convert into datetime.datetime object

Tags: python, python-datetime

I want to count days until birthday. I have string with date of birth:

```
"1949-10-09T00:25:51.304Z"
```

and

```
tday = datetime.now().isoformat()
```

that returns

```
2020-08-05T21:02:31.532123
<class 'str'>
```

and I wonder how to create a delta time of this two strings.

I see the difference between those strings:

```
"1949-10-09T00:25:51.304Z"     # date of birth
"2020-08-05T21:02:31.532123"   # today
```

Do I have to change "today" string (slice to get:

```
"2020-08-05T21:02:31.532"
```

and then concatenate "Z" to get:

```
"2020-08-05T21:02:31.532Z"
```

and then convert this into object using datetime.strptime(),
and convert birthday date into an object date too, using this?

```
birthday = datetime.fromisoformat('1949-10-09T00:25:51.304Z')
```

Or there is a smarter way of doing that?

To get the birthday string I have to use that function that parse JSON file.

```
date=get_double_nested_table_data(0, "dob", "date")
birthday = datetime.fromisoformat(date)
now = datetime.now()
delta = now - birthday
```

It doesn't work.

I did that using answer below:

```
def get_days_until_birthday(index: int, first_table: str, second_table: str):
    birthday_str = get_double_nested_table_data(index, first_table, second_table)
    birthday = datetime.strptime(birthday_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
    now = datetime.now()
    delta = now - birthday
    return delta.days
```

and that returns rows like that:
[weird ints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDuSI.png)

I changed that function into this:

```
def get_days_until_birthday(index: int, first_table: str, second_table: str):
    now = datetime.now()
    year = now.year
    birthday_str = get_double_nested_table_data(index, first_table, second_table)
    birthday_str = str(year) + birthday_str[4:]
    birthday = datetime.strptime(birthday_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
    now = datetime.now()
    delta = now - birthday
    return delta.days
```

and that works fine only if birthday will come in this year. That function don't return correct days if birthday will be in the next year.

Could you know how to change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is substracting the two datetimes which give you the timedelta between them

```
from datetime import datetime

birthday_str = '1949-10-09T00:25:51.304Z'
# you can remove the Z by slicing
birthday = datetime.fromisoformat(birthday_str[:-1])
# or with strptime
birthday = datetime.strptime(birthday_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
now = datetime.now()
delta = now - birthday

# return the number of days (positive) there is between now and birthday date
return (now - birthday).days if birthday < now else (birthday - now).days
```

strptime format [reference](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes):

**%Y** *is the year in 4 dig*its*
**%m*** the month in 2 digits
**%d** *the day in 2 digits*
**T** *to still match the format of the string you're using*
**%H** *is the hour*
**:** *to still match the format of the string you're using*
**%M** *is the minutes*
**%S** *is for the seconds*
**.** *to still match the format of the string you're using*
**%f** *is for the microseconds*
**Z** *to still match the format of the string you're using*

Comment: that code returns error: ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '1966-06-26T11:50:25.558Z'

Comment: that returns error again. I think my string with birthday does not match isoformat. Birthday string don't have so many numbers after the dot.

Comment: I think it's the Z behind I edit my code for it to work for you using strptime

Comment: nice! can you accept my answer since it resolve your issue =)

Comment: I was wrong, the results in the database are e.g. 19764, 25868 ...

Comment: I changed my post :)

Comment: Hey, so i understand what you want is the absolute (positive) number of days from now to a different date, so I have revised my answer. It is functioning for dates before now and after.

Comment: Thank you very much. There was another problem - leap year. I had in my JSON one date with 29 February and datetime object return an error "day is out of range" :) But I solved it.